# Property 'value' does not exist on type 'FilterMetadata | > FilterMetadata[]'

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, primeng-datatable

I have an application generated using Jhipster PrimeNG Blueprint. It enables table filtering using 'filters' as

```
this.myTable.filters.filterField.value
```

Since filters definition in table.ds has been updated from

```
@Input() filters: { [s: string]: FilterMetadata; } = {};
```

to

```
filters: { [s: string]: FilterMetadata | FilterMetadata[]; };
```

on upgrading app to v11 is breaking giving error

> Property 'value' does not exist on type 'FilterMetadata |
> FilterMetadata[]'. Property 'value' does not exist on type
> 'FilterMetadata[]'.ts(2339)

FilterMetadata definition is:

```
export interface FilterMetadata {
    value?: any;
    matchMode?: string;
    operator?: string;
}
```

I am not able to get rid of this error. Besides global search, column level filters use same code. Is there a work around to tackle this change without breaking application?